# How to get Dervied column in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a column name email in which some records are present as NULL,' '(a single space)

and some general entries like a@gmail.com.By using Dervied column i have split by using code

LEN(EMP_EMAIL) > 2.It is returing me TRUE in column in which email is present.I don't know

the next step,how to use these TRUE value column and put my data(Contains Email) in a new

Column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is quite unclear, but I think you are actually looking for the [Conditional Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137886.aspx) transformation. It is used to split data based on your criteria, so you can use it to send the valid email addresses to the next step in the data flow.

The Derived Column transformation is not suitable because it transforms all rows in the input, it does not filter out rows in any way. And NULL is not at all the same thing as a single space, by the way.

If this doesn't help, please explain more clearly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to transfer data to another column & condition on which data must be transfer is  that only records which has email present should be transfer.Remember email column contains mailous entries like NULL & Single Space.

Comment: I have resolved my problem my making use of SQl Task in SSIS.